# How to access the properties of an instance of a derived class which is passed as a parameter in the form of the base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism, derived-class, base-class

In C# I have a base class and a derived class.

I have a function which has the base class as an input parameter

```
public void SomeFunction(BaseClass InstanceOfDerivedClass)
```

Is there a way I can access the properties specific to the derived class, even though it has been passed as a base class? Could I use GetType or Cast or something like that?

I appreciate that the solutions may not be elegant but at the moment the alternative is to repeat this function many times for the different derived classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do this (bad way):

```
public void SomeFunction(BaseClass instanceOfDerivedClass)
{
    DerivedClass derived = null;

    if(instanceOfDerivedClass is DerivedClass)
    {
        derived = instanceOfDerivedClass as DerivedClass;
        // Do stuff like :
        int prop = derived.DerivedProperty;
    }
}
```

Or, as suggested by Eric (good way):

```
public void SomeFunction(BaseClass instanceOfDerivedClass)
{
    DerivedClass derived = instanceOfDerivedClass as DerivedClass;

    if(derived != null)
    {
        // Do stuff like :
        int prop = derived.DerivedProperty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Right idea. Extremely wordy implementation. How about simply `DerivedClass derived = instanceOfDerivedClass as DerivedClass; if (derived != null) ... `

Answer (score 4):

Casting should definitely do the trick, since the reference in the heap is to that class.  Maybe something like:

```
if (InstanceOfDerivedClass is DerivedClass)
```

And in that block you can cast it and interact with it.

But the bigger question is, why do you need to?  It sounds like this method is using the wrong abstraction if the type being accepted as an argument isn't the correct type.  This is breaking Liskov Substitution and looks like a prime candidate for refactoring the design.  (Of which we don't know enough to help much.)

Comment: Can you expand a bit on how to cast it? Sorry for being a noob.

Comment: @Caustix: No problem.  The most intuitive and elegant way would probably be as Amaud pointed out, using the "as" keyword to interpret the variable as a different type.  "InstanceOfDerivedClass as DerivedClass"  It's also worth noting in your code that your variable starts with a capital letter (which is why the code interpreter on StackOverflow shows it like a type instead). This isn't strictly idiomatic C#.  It's more standard to start with a lowercase letter. And, as before, I can't stress enough that this type casting isn't an ideal solution. It will work, but it's a workaround.

Comment: @David. Thanks. I'm going to start another question which will expand on the wider problem and see if anyone can help. Will paste the link here once it's ready. Thanks again.

Comment: @David. Posted the wider issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593305/seeking-a-more-elegant-method-to-populate-a-wpf-datagrid-with-dynamic-columns-on) if you're interested. One solution to this other problem involved doing the above.