# Get attribute of derived C# class passed as base class to generic method

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

I'm trying to determine the value of an attribute on a derived class, when it's been passed into a method through a base class parameter.

For example, complete code sample below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DerivedClass DC = new DerivedClass();
        ProcessMessage(DC);
    }

    private static void ProcessMessage(BaseClass baseClass)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetTargetSystemFromAttribute(baseClass));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string GetTargetSystemFromAttribute<T>(T msg)
    {
        TargetSystemAttribute TSAttribute = (TargetSystemAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(T), typeof(TargetSystemAttribute));

        if (TSAttribute == null)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Message type {0} has no TargetSystem attribute and/or the TargetSystemType property was not set.", typeof(T).ToString()));

        return TSAttribute.TargetSystemType;
    }
}

public class BaseClass
{}

[TargetSystem(TargetSystemType="OPSYS")]
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public sealed class TargetSystemAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string TargetSystemType { get; set; }
}
```

So, in the above example, I had intended that the generic *GetTargetSystemFromAttribute* method returns "OPSYS".

But, because the DerivedClass instance has been passed to *ProcessMessage* as the base class, *Attribute.GetAttribute* is not finding anything because it's treating the DerivedClass as the Base Class, which does not have the attribute or the value I'm interested in.

In the real-world there are dozens of Derived Classes, so I was hoping to avoid lots of:

```
if (baseClass is DerivedClass)
```

...which is suggested as the answer in the question [How to access the properties of an instance of a derived class which is passed as a parameter in the form of the base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587667/how-to-access-the-properties-of-an-instance-of-a-derived-class-which-is-passed-a) (which relates to a similar issue, but with properties). I was hoping because I'm interested in Attributes there's a nicer way of doing it, especially as I have dozens of derived classes.

So, here's the question. Is there any way I can obtain the TargetSystemType value of the TargetSystem Attribute on my derived classes in a low-maintenance way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should change this line:

```
(TargetSystemAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(T), typeof(TargetSystemAttribute));
```

with this:

```
msg.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TargetSystemAttribute), true)[0] as TargetSystemAttribute;
```

P.S. GetCustomAttributes returns array and I picked up first element for example where only 1 attribute is expected, you may need to change, but the logic is the same.

Comment: Ups, it should be rewritten in a short way: in your code instead typeof(T) use msg.GetType() :)

Comment: So I now have: TargetSystemAttribute TSAttribute = (TargetSystemAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(msg.GetType(), typeof(TargetSystemAttribute));  And yes, it works. Bravo and thank you.

Comment: Yup :) This happend because TypeOf(T) returns type of reference variable, but instead you needed type of actual object, which is - msg.GetType().